# What impact has air resistance beneath vehicles?

Tags: energy, friction

Let's say that a car travels 100km in one hour consuming 5 litters of gasoline.
How much gasoline would consume this car if between the left and right wheels would be a deep hole, meaning that there is no friction between the car's body and the ground?

Comment: Impossible to say. The "deep hole" changes the profile of the car, and possibly the projected area (if I have the right mental picture). You cannot simply answer this. If it's a small car to begin with, and most of the friction is rolling friction, the answer is "very little". What kind of answer are you expecting? "A lot"? "A little"? "13.2345%"?

Comment: Of course that there are many factors which can make the answer difficult. Perhaps "more" or "less" would be sufficient. But common cars have a pretty similar aerodynamics.

Comment: See [this thread](http://ecomodder.com/forum/showthread.php/does-reducing-ground-clearance-really-reduce-drag-1783.html) for some links to research in this area (also some rubbish and some "it depends" evidence)